# Document Locator Connection Configuration Settings Location

Tags: file-location

I'm looking for the registry file or some kind of ini file that stores the Connection Configuration settings to the Document Locator repository. To clarify: I need the NT Security, SQL Server Name, and SQL Server Database Name settings.

My reason for needing these settings is so that I can apply these settings to machines on my network so I do not have to manually configure Document Locator for each system.

Answer (score 0):

Contacted Columbiasoft Support and the file is located at:

%appdata%\Columbiasoft\CSSCatalog.sdf